# iOS Share ExtensionでURL通信が失敗する(実機のみ)

Tags: xcode, ios-app-extension

環境
Xcode 7.1.1
Deployment Target 8.0
実機&シミュレータ iPhone5S iOS 8.2
サーバ Rails 4.2.3

実機のShare ExtensionでdidSelectPostメソッド内でURL通信を行うと次のエラーが発生してしまいサーバと通信できません。
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "操作を完了できませんでした。`
シミュレータを利用している時は問題なく通信ができています。
実機では上記エラーが発生し、Railsのログが動いていないことからサーバに接続もできていないようです。
実機の時は接続するURLをmacが接続しているIPアドレスと同じアドレスを指定し、macと同じWiFi環境で接続しています。

Xcode6で作成したプロジェクトのShare Extensionは実機でも問題なく通信できていますが
問題が発生したプロジェクトはXcode7になった後で作成したものでXcodeが不具合の原因なのかとも考えています。

どなたか情報お持ちでしたら教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: URL通信とは単にhttp通信のことでしょうか？ 1.App Transport Securityへの対応はされていますか？ 2.エクステンションへのアクセス権限は適切に与えていますか？　の2点を確認してみてください。

Comment: URL通信はhttp通信のことです。ATSは確認済みで設定があってもなくても同じ症状が発生します。すいません、エクステンションのアクセス権限が何のことかよく分かりません。App Groupなら収容アプリと同じグループに設定しています。

Comment: Shareエクステンションの場合はコンテナアプリケーションの通信が可能なら特に権限いらないですね、失礼いたしました。接続がWifiとのことで、モバイルデータ通信がOFFになっているという要因でもなさそうです。

Comment: 試しに新規にアプリを作成してShareエクステンション内でURL通信を試してみましたが、シミュレータなら問題なく通信できるのにやはり実機だと通信できませんでした。誰か同じ症状の人いないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決できました。
App Extensionを格納している収容アプリを実機に再インストールして、URL通信を行ってみた所問題なくサーバと通信することができました。